# FindAllByColumn(List<String> columnValues) in ElasticsearchRepository is not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have SpringBoot connected to my elastic search running under docker.
In ElasticsearchRepository

- `findAllById(Iterable<BigInteger> ids)` is working fine
- `findBySicCode(String sicCode)` and `findAllBySicCode(string sicCode)` working fine

  But when i try
- `findAllBySicCode(List<String> sicCodes)` is giving me QueryShardException[Failed to parse query] parse_exception: Cannot parse '[13201]': Encountered " "]" "] "" at line 1, column 6.

Here 13201 i was passing in the list.

Not able to understand something wrong with ES Index or with my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try, `findAllBySicCodeIn(List<String> sicCodes)`

Here is a nice documentation about https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation

Answer (score 1):

Try with: 
`findAllBySicCodes(List<String> sicCodes)`.

Comment: This is not working!
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property sicCodes found for type ElasticCategory! Did you mean 'sicCode'?

Comment: the query method name should match the attribute in your entity.
For example, if you have an attribute like this: `List<String>sicCodes `, then your method name query should be like this: `findAllBySicCodes(List<String> sicCodes)`.

Comment: that i know but check the question 
findBySicCode(String sicCode) and findAllBySicCode(string sicCode) if these two are working then property is sicCode but for list its not working this is problem 
i don't know what are you solving

Comment: then the solution proposed by @shaunak should work.